# Google Map API how to set marker for current location

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I'm learning google map API and stuck at this problem when i'm trying to add the current coordinate to an array. Here is my code:

```
var locations = [];
```

In initialize() i have:

```
function initialize() {
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 10,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        navigationControl: true,
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

    add_location('Place 1', 37.2846372, -123.3270422);
    set_current_location();
    set_markers(new google.maps.LatLngBounds(), map);
}
```

The first marker is set, while the set_current_location() doesn't seem to work. Here is the rest of the code:

```
// add new location to the locations array
function add_location(description, lastitude, longtitude) {
    locations.push([description, lastitude, longtitude]);
}

// Set all the markers in the location arrays and bound/frame the map
function set_markers(bounds, map) {
    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: map
        });
        bounds.extend(marker.position);
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
            return function () {
                infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));
    }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
}

// Get current location based on the IP Address
function set_current_location() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
            position.coords.longitude);
            var myLat = position.coords.latitude;
            var myLong = position.coords.longitude;
            add_location('My location', position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
        });
    } else {
        alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }
}
```

Can anyone help or give me a hint? I would like to add the current location to the locations array so I can keep track of how many locations I have added. Thank you so much.

Comment: call `set_markers` at the end of the callback of `getCurrentPosition` and not in `initialize`. Retrieving the users location is an asynchronous process, the result isn't available yet when initialize is finished.

Comment: I agree with Dr. Molle. I saw the same thing. getCurrentPosition() is an async call that gets executed in the background, so there is no guarantee in the above code that when set_markers() is called that getCurrentPosition() has finished. Putting the set_markers() call at the end of getCurrentPosition() will guarantee that the user's geolocation will be finished before the markers are placed on the map.

Answer (score 1):

If you just move `set_markers()` to the end of `success` callback of `getCurrentPosition()` and user refuse to share his location, you won't get the map but just gray area. There is no `center` set for your map which is required property. Better to define it like:

```
var myOptions = {
    zoom: 10,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.339386, -121.894955),
    mapTypeControl: true,
    navigationControl: true,
}
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
...
```

Additionally, you can also call `set_markers()` at the end of `error` callback of `getCurrentPosition()`, so in case that user refuse sharing of his location, you can show available locations:

```
// Get current location based on the IP Address
function set_current_location() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            /*
            var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                             position.coords.longitude);
            var myLat = position.coords.latitude;
            var myLong = position.coords.longitude;
            */
            add_location('My location', 
                        position.coords.latitude, 
                        position.coords.longitude);

            set_markers(new google.maps.LatLngBounds(), map);
        }, function error(err) {
            console.log('error: ' + err.message);
            set_markers(new google.maps.LatLngBounds(), map);            
        });
    } else {
        alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }
}
```

See [example at jsbin](http://jsbin.com/xudeq/2/edit)

Comment: thanks, your code actually solved the problem but my goal is a little further than that. I would like to save the position (long/last) of the current position to the array directions for further use. Unfortunately after set_current_location() the current location is not pushed to the array. How can I get/save that data? Thanks

Comment: How do you check that? If you check that in `initialize()` function after `set_current_location()` then you will get wrong result because `getCurrentPosition()` is async function. You have to check how `locations` change in `add_location()` function. If I share my location I get marker and variable `locations` updated. See updated jsbin example and open console log.